# Call generic Method with multiple generic Types without specifying every single generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, methods, call

So what I have is a generic Method with multiple generic types.

Now I'd like to call this Method this way (using the types of a and b and just specifying the return type):

```
class Example
{

    T1 GenericMethod<T1, T2, T3>(T2 parameter1, T3 parameter2)

    {
        T1 returnValue = default(T1);

        // ... Do something with returnType, parameter1 and parameter2

        return returnValue;
    }

    void AccessGenericMethod()
    {
        var a = new Foo1();
        var b = new Foo2();
        var result = GenericMethod<ReturnType>(a, b); // doesn't work
    }
}
```

And i would like to avoid to call `GenericMethod` this way

```
var result GenericMethod<ReturnType, Foo1, Foo2>(a, b);
```

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/partial-type-inference-in-net.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, there is no partial type inference: You must either specify all or none of the generic arguments, but the latter only works if the compiler is able to infer all types from context. Return types cannot be infered (except for some special cases such as lambdas), so what you want to do is not possible.

Two workarounds:

A: Move `T1` from the method to the class

```
class Example<T1>
{
    T1 GenericMethod<T2, T3>(T2 parameter1, T3 parameter2)
```

B: Replace `T2` and `T3` by `object`

```
class Example
{
    T1 GenericMethod<T1>(object parameter1, object parameter2)
```

Comment: @Sebastian, can you give an example of a case where the compiler wouldn't be able to infer all types? The example in the question, `var result = GenericMethod<ReturnType>(a, b)` seems like something the compiler should be able to infer. The parameters are of a known type from where they're declared and the return type is explicitly specified in the method call.

Comment: @HotN _Should_, yes, maybe. But C# was not designed that way. It's simply not a feature the C# developers have implemented.

Comment: Ok, I'll just hold out hope that they do in a future version of C# and accept needing to write just a little extra code until then. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution

```
class Example
{
    T1 GenericMethod<T1, T2, T3>(T2 parameter1, T3 parameter2, out T1 returnValue)
    {
        returnValue = default(T1);

        // ... Do something with returnType, parameter1 and parameter2

        return returnValue = new T1();
    }

    void AccessGenericMethod()
    {
        var a = new Foo1();
        var b = new Foo2();
        GenericMethod(a, b, out ReturnType result1); // work!
        ReturnType result2 = GenericMethod(a, b, out result2);
    }
}
```